# Load Server Side function onfocus in Html and asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html

I am unable to call Server Side LoadStudent() method as focus enters the HTML drop down list.

**Server Side Coding**

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class FeeEntry
    Public Sub LoadStudent()
        MsgBox("Called")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT StudentName FROM Student")
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Connection = con
            'con.Open()
            DropDownList1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "StudentName"
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "StudentName"
            DropDownList1.DataBind()
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Sub

End Class
```

**Html Code**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID = "DropDownList1" runat="server" onfocus="LoadStudent()"  CssClass ="form-control">
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onfocus` event is going to be a primarily client-side event, which is used to trigger Javascript and other client-based actions.

What you'll likely want to do is call the `LoadStudent()` method within the `Page_Load` event in your page on its initial load and remove the previous `onfocus` attribute :

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
      ' If it is the first time the page is being loaded, bind your data '
      If Not IsPostBack Then
          LoadStudent()
      End If
End Sub
```

If that isn't feasible, you would probably want to create another server-side event that would perform your loading and set `AutoPostBack="True"` on your DropDownList, along with the event that you decide to use.

For instance, if you had a separate list that contained all of your individual Students, you could call the `LoadStudent()` event when one of these changed :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="StudentsList" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="LoadStudents">...</asp>DropDownList>
```

Comment: Brother drop down list will be populated as per the selected student class so it has to be written in onfocus or onblur i can't write it in page load event

Comment: Could you set an event when your specific student selection was changed that would update the DropDownList? Assuming that your students are in a separate list, simply set up an event to determine when it changed and call the `LoadStudent()` method then.